# Iterate over java.util.BitSet in Scala

Tags: scala, iterator, bitset

What is the best answer for iterating over a java BitSet in Scala?

I currently have this:

```
var setBit = -1
Iterator.continually { setBit = bitSet.nextSetBit(setBit + 1); setBit }
      .takeWhile(_ >= 0)
```

What is the most accepted way to do this?
The reason I am not confident about this approach is because of the mutable setBit declaration and the `setBit = bitSet.nextSetBit(setBit + 1); setBit` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.iterate` instead of `.continually`. Then there's no need for a mutable `var`.

```
Iterator.iterate(bitSet.nextSetBit(0))(x => bitSet.nextSetBit(x+1))
        .takeWhile(_ >= 0)
```